# jQuery writing data to .json file with getJSON

Tags: jquery, database, json, getjson

Is it possible or is it a one way stream?
I can't find any documentation of it, and if not what's the best way to save user input data, without using a full-blown database?

Comment: You can check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968959/how-to-read-json-file-format-and-how-to-write-the-json-in-c-sharp-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a server side script that will handle the AJAX request and store the user input somewhere. It could be a file, database, ... You cannot modify content on the server using pure javascript without some handler on this server.

Comment: thanx @Darin Dimitrov, and is there some simple handler so I won't have to resort to PHP?

Comment: @IlyaD, what do you mean by a simple handler? You need a server side language. PHP seems easy enough.